# Static vector of array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, multidimensional-array, 2d

I would like to have a 2D static vector that can be extended in one direction. A static vector of array sounded right to me:

```
struct A
{
    public:
        static std::vector<std::array<float, 3> > theTable;
};
```

I tried to access it from main with:

```
A::theTable.push_back({0.0, 0.0, 0.0});
```

But I get "no matching function for call to `std::vector<std::array<float, 3ul> >::push_back(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)`"

How can I declare this vector of array and then use if properly from anywhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like you have not defined `theTable`

---

```
struct A
{
    public:
        static std::vector<std::array<float, 3> > theTable;
};
std::vector<std::array<float, 3> > A::theTable; //define
```

Comment: Indeed that was needed. But I also need paddy's answer to get it to work!

Answer (score 2):

You're pushing an array of doubles, not floats.  Change the `0.0` values to `0.0f`.

If you still have issues, it might be that you need an extra set of braces.  When I compile that in G++ with all warnings, I get the warning:

> suggest braces around initialization of subobject [-Wmissing-braces]

So, the correct code should be:

```
A::theTable.push_back({{0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}});
```